# How to get uri address of a nested resources using vue js and laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, vue.js

I am having problem fetching the uri of a nested resource when using vue js. See below code.

ReservationController.php

```
public function index($id)
    {   

        $student = Student::with(['sectionSubjects','sectionSubjects.section', 
                    'sectionSubjects.subject'])->findOrFail($id);

        return $student->sectionSubjects;   

    }
```

all.js

```
methods:{

        fetchSubjects: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.$http({
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/reservation/id/student',
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(function (reservations){
                this.$set('reservations', reservations.data);
                console.log('success');

            }, function (response){
                console.log('failed');
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem here is, getting the value of the id of this url http://localhost:8000/reservation/id/student. Is there a way to get the id of the parameter of the index() method? Also here's my route list https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJNOa.jpg

Comment: Your app would need to know the ID you're trying to send the request to, so somewhere you need to fetch the reservation with an http request.

Comment: @Jeff Yeah that's my problem I cannot find ways to fetch that ID before fetching the uri. Can you give me example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the Student ID returned from the `index` method in your controller?

If so, you need to do it like this in your controller:

```
public function index($id)
{

    $student = Student::with(['sectionSubjects','sectionSubjects.section',
                'sectionSubjects.subject'])->findOrFail($id);

    return [
        'student_id' => $id,
        'reservations' => $student->sectionSubjects
    ];

}
```

and to retrieve the Student ID on your JS like this:

```
methods: {

    fetchSubjects: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.$http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/reservation/id/student',
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function (response) {
            this.$set('studentId', response.student_id); // <-- change here
            this.$set('reservations', response.reservations.data); // <-- change here
            console.log('success');
        }, function (response) {
            console.log('failed');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail right because the id will be undefined - http://localhost:8000/reservation/id/student'

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question, can you show the code you use to load the page where the fetchSubjects is called? Ideally, your controller and view code.